# How to render full profile2?

Tags: 7, entities

I am tring to load a full profile2.

I a trying the following code

```
<?php 
$uid = user_load($node->uid);
$profile2_p = profile2_load_by_user($uid, 'profile2_profile');
print render($profile2_p);
?>
```

I get an error saying object can't be used as array.

If I print_r $profile2_p then I get an array relating to the correct profile2 entity. How can I render this entity?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you can get a renderable array using profile2_view():

```
/**
 * View a profile.
 *
 * @see Profile::view()
 */
function profile2_view($profile, $view_mode = 'full', $langcode = NULL, $page = NULL) {
  return $profile->view($view_mode, $langcode, $page);
}
```

https://git.drupalcode.org/project/profile2/-/blob/7.x-1.x/profile2.module#L1084

See also that modules hook_user_view() which does the same:

https://git.drupalcode.org/project/profile2/-/blob/7.x-1.x/profile2.module#L399

```
/**
 * Implements hook_user_view().
 */
function profile2_user_view($account, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  foreach (profile2_get_types() as $type => $profile_type) {
    if ($profile_type->userView && $profile = profile2_load_by_user($account, $type)) {
      if (profile2_access('view', $profile)) {
        $account->content['profile_' . $type] = array(
          '#type' => 'user_profile_category',
          '#title' => $profile_type->getTranslation('label'),
          '#prefix' => '<a id="profile-' . $profile->type . '"></a>',
        );
        $account->content['profile_' . $type]['view'] = $profile->view($view_mode);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With a single entity in your code, you can:

```
render($profile2_p->view($some_view_mode));
```